# How do you set folder to a parameter for FOR EACH LOOP in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm beginning SSIS,
I need to know in this screen:

[image]

In the Enumerator Configuration, How can I parameter the folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set it under Expressions > Directory

Here is a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/changliw/2010/07/19/ssis-dynamically-specify-folder-path-for-foreach-file-enumerator-in-foreach-loop-container/) demonstrating it.